# Task.Factory.StartNew() runs on wrong thread if Modal dialog opened

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, com, task-parallel-library

Can anyone explain why, if a C++ application runs a .NET UI component (all on the main thread) which in turn spawns a modal .NET dialog and then tries to use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();` in a `Task.Factory.StartNew` call the task is run on a worker thread? This doesn't happen if I do not show the dialog or if I store off the context before showing the dialog.

I tried to create a dummy program to show it but failed, I think it's likely related to having a main process which is COM.

Any ideas?

Ok my code looks like this

```
private void RunStateMachine(IQ4UpgraderState State)
{
    _State = State;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StateMachine(), _TokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void StateMachine()
{
    switch (_State)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

When the Task is started the current context is the Main Thread but when the StateMachine call runs it is on a worker thread if ***and only if***  I have opened a modal dialogue prior to running this code. The context returned by TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() appears to be correct at the point of starting my task. I have even compared what is returned in both situations and there appears to be no difference.

Comment: Can you trace when exactly does `SynchronizationContext.Current` change?

Comment: If I recall, the context looks fine as it is used, yet the task runs on another thread. I shall go and reproduce and confirm...

Comment: To answer your question no I cannot since it appears to be correct at the time I use it. I have tried to use a VB6 project wrapping a simple C# project to reproduce this but it seems fine, so maybe it's an MFC issue as that is what the container is in the above case

Comment: The problem is that the SynchronizationContext isn't set yet when you use the Factory.  This happens on-the-fly, just creating a new Form() is enough.  It is important that this happens on the main thread, the one that pumps a message loop.  The factory call must be made on the main thread as well.

Comment: I have confirmed that the factory call ALWAYS happens on the main thread. In fact there is no attempt in this area of code to use any other thread, yet if you load a modal .Net window elsewhere before calling this code, the problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. In COM, when you are running in a single-threaded apartment, it is just all the same thread...

Comment: Yeah but the modal process spawns extra message loops on that thread apparently, though it's not intuitive for my poor brain on a Friday evening! I think what may be happening is that the current thread context gets associated with the spawned loop which when used for the task callback goes wrong somehow and .Net decides it needs to use the thread pool to satisfy the message.